# Change TextField Value based on a combination of Comboboxes selection JavaFX and Java 1.7

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have multible comboBoxes, based on the section of a comboBox combination I would like to set the value of TextField. Say for example we have a fruit type order form, where we need to 1) Select Fruit's Type 2) Fruit's Count. Then Set the TextField accordingly to the Type and count. Here is an example.

```
public class FruitsOrderController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox fruitTypeBox, fruitCountBox ;
    @FXML
    private TextField fruitOrder; 

    ObservableList<String> fruitTypeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Apples", "Oranges");
    ObservableList<Integer> applesCountList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(5,6,7);
    ObservableList<Integer> orangesCountList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(1,2,3);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        fruitTypeBox.setItems(fruitTypeList);
        fruitTypeBox.setValue("Oranges");
        fruitCountBox.setItems(orangesCountList);
        fruitCountBox.setValue(3);
    }
    @FXML
    public void fruitOrder(){
        if (fruitTypeBox.getValue().equals("Apples")){
            fruitCountBox.setItems(applesCountList);
            fruitCountBox.setValue(7);
         }

        if (fruitTypeBox.getValue().equals("Oranges")){
            fruitCountBox.setItems(orangesCountList);
            fruitCountBox.setValue(3);
        }
      }
  }
```

Now, I made the following selection 1) Fruits Type = Oranges 2) Fruits Count 3 and I want to change my TextFiled to reflect my choice as demonstrated in the image below.
[image]

Comment: I modified the question accordingly with example, please take a look. Thanks again for helping out!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to listen to changes in subcomboBox you could add a listener like this:

```
subcomboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> selected, String oldSelect, String newSelect) {
    if (oldSelect != null) {
      switch(oldSelect) {
        case "ABC": textfield.setText("ABC");  break;
        case "DEF": textfield.setText("DEF"); break;
        //....
      }
    }
    if (newSelect != null) {
      switch(newSelect) {case "ABC": textfield.setText("ABC");  break;
        case "DEF": textfield.setText("DEF"); break;
      }
    }  
  }
});
```

Comment: I have modified the question to address an inquiry. Can you please see the updated question and modify your answer. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: it's still not working. Here is the project on Google Drive. Can you take a look please? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0kPmhDSNVBPZEtGVWJiQUpZUW8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding listeners to the `SelectionModel`s of the `ComboBox`es.

Also it would improve code quality, if you create a class `Fruit` that groups the data and provides a method creating the output `String`:

```
public class Fruit {

    private final String type;
    private final ObservableList<Integer> counts;
    private final int defaultCount;

    public Fruit(String type, int defaultCount, Integer... counts) {
        if (type == null || counts == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null not allowed");
        }
        this.type = type;
        this.counts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(counts);

        if (this.counts.contains(null)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null not allowed as count");
        }

        if (!this.counts.contains(defaultCount)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("default count must be contained in counts");
        }
        this.defaultCount = defaultCount;
    }

    public String getText(Integer count) {
        return count == null ? null : count + " " + type;
    }

    public ObservableList<Integer> getCounts() {
        return counts;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getDefaultCount() {
        return defaultCount;
    }

}
```

Using this class you can modify your code like this:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<Fruit> fruitTypeBox;
@FXML
private ComboBox<Integer> fruitCountBox;

@FXML
private TextField fruitOrder;

private final ObservableList<Fruit> fruitTypeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Fruit("Apples", 7, 5, 6, 7),
        new Fruit("Oranges", 3, 1, 2, 3));

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    fruitTypeBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<Fruit>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(Fruit object) {
            return object.getType();
        }

        @Override
        public Fruit fromString(String string) {
            for (Fruit fruit : fruitTypeList) {
                if (fruit.getType().equals(fruit)) {
                    return fruit;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    fruitTypeBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Fruit>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Fruit> observable, Fruit oldValue, Fruit newValue) {
            if (newValue == null) {
                fruitOrder.setText(null);
                fruitCountBox.setItems(null);
            } else {
                fruitCountBox.setItems(newValue.getCounts());
                int defaultCount = newValue.getDefaultCount();
                fruitCountBox.setValue(defaultCount);
                fruitOrder.setText(newValue.getText(defaultCount));
            }
        }
    });

    fruitCountBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Integer> observable, Integer oldValue, Integer newValue) {
            Fruit fruit = fruitTypeBox.getValue();
            fruitOrder.setText(fruit == null ? null : fruit.getText(newValue));
        }
    });

    fruitTypeBox.setItems(fruitTypeList);
    fruitTypeBox.setValue(fruitTypeList.get(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian, can you modify your code for Java 1.7. I am receiving lambada expression not supported.

Comment: @Moe: It's easy to do this on your own using anonymus classes, since `this` is not used, but I've modified the code nonetheless.